# SQL server extension in PHP manual

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

I need in my website to add php to the server side for IIS , I installed the PHP form the :

http://windows.php.net/download#php-7.0

the last version and unziped to the C:\PHP also I added the Wincache extension. Beside that i add the Environment variable and the PHP to IIS Manager. so PHP site loads perfect, so my problem is my database is MS SQL SERVER so I need to add the extension to the php . ALTHOUGHT I dont have a php.ini File instead there are 2 files  **php.ini-production** and **php.ini-development** . I installed the driver form : **https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098** 
 I dont know how to go further .!! i tried to connect to my database but I got this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

i edited the 2 ini files and removed the ; but there are no lines related to the sqlsrv , i tried to add them manually but also did not work .

ANY IDEAS , PLEASE !!

Comment: It's not an IIS issue, `This function was REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.`  You should use the PDO driver.

Comment: @chris85 so how should i connect to the  sql server

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can't use `mssql_connect()` anymore, `sqlsrv_connect()` is the prefered method since PHP 5.3.2, if I'm not mistaken.

I've created a "How to install Microsoft’s SQL Server Driver for PHP" that you can find at https://www.saotn.org/install-microsoft-sql-server-driver-php/.